# How can i include the fonts of ratchet js framework in my html?

Tags: ratchet-2

How can I include the fonts of ratchet js framework in my html? I included ratchet.js and ratchet.css, but the icons don't work.

Comment: Please show your code, what the result should look like and what it actually does.

Comment: http://codepen.io/ismailismail/pen/OpJbvr

Comment: Please have a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Code has to be included in the question itself. It is still unclear which behavior you expect and what is happening instead.